# what values I have to use to crop a pdf using sejda

Tags: pdf, crop

I'm tring to use [sejda shell](http://www.sejda.org/shell-interface/tutorial/) to crop a double page PDF and have a output with a single one page and cropping the crop sign. 
I'm not able to understand, in crop option, what is the unit of measurement for the cropAreas values. Comeone can help me?

Comment: I think I resolve: the values seems to be in points...